# How to check Django Form Submission Against Value in Database Table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to create a function in my views.py that checks a users date submission against values already submitted to the database:

```
def make_booking(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_date = form.cleaned_data.get("date_of_booking")
            existing_booking = Booking.objects.get('date_of_booking').items()
            for booking in existing_booking:
                if booking == new_date:
                    messages.success(request, "THIS DATE IS ALREADY TAKEN")
                else:
                    form.save()
                    print('form saved')
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                return redirect(get_bookings)
            if not request.user.is_authenticated:
                return redirect(get_bookings_guest)
```

If the date already exists in the database then I want it to show a message saying the date already exists. I have written the above which seems correct to me but I get this error: "Exception Value:
too many values to unpack (expected 2)".

Please could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if form.is_valid():

    new_date = form.cleaned_data.get("date_of_booking")
    
    if Booking.objects.filter(date_of_booking=new_date).exists():
        messages.success(request, "THIS DATE IS ALREADY TAKEN")
    else:
        form.save()
        print('form saved')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - thank-you! Do you have any suggestions if I want to check the time of the booking as well? So raise a message if a date/time already exist. I don't want to actually stop a booking for a particular date you see. I want to stop it if that date and time has already been booked.

Answer (score 0):

How about filtering the `Booking` objects in database for all entries with `new_date`? Make the `if` comparison based on the number of entries returned; if zero, `new_date` is a new date.

Assuming that `new_date` is a `datetime` object, you could do this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    new_date = form.cleaned_data.get("date_of_booking")
    existing_bookings = Booking.objects.filter(date_of_booking=new_date)
    if existing_bookings.count() == 0:
        form.save()
        print('form saved')
    else:
        messages.success(request, "THIS DATE IS ALREADY TAKEN")
```

Comment: Thanks! This would have worked if I just wanted to prevent duplicate dates. My intentions were ambiguous as I was trying to solve date and then time separately.

Answer (score 0):

Sample with time

```
new_date = form.cleaned_data.get("date_of_booking")
new_time = form.cleaned_data.get("time_of_booking")

if Booking.objects.filter(date_of_booking=new_date).filter(
        time_of_booking=new_time).exists():
    messages.success(request, "THIS DATE AND TIME IS ALREADY TAKEN")

else:
    form.save()
    print('form saved')
```